How to turn WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER to on from off
I am troubleshooting a network problem after I upgraded from Centos 7 to RHEL9. The only difference I can see different from a Centos 7 host is: WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER: on vs RHEL9 WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER: off From nmcli device show interfacename
How do I set up the property WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER to on. I have been reading but I can't find the correct answer to it and Google AI is terrible on this subject.
Thanks in advance for reading my question.

Sound a bit like an XYProblem to me. Why do you want to do that? What the real/ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? Or did you mistyped off to on as on to off (as @telcoM seems to have assumed)?

First, check the network cable. Ensure it's plugged in to correct ports at both ends, and is not kinked or otherwise damaged.
The WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER reflects the state of the LINK light of the NIC. If it is off, it means the NIC is not detecting a valid incoming signal.
Possible causes and fixes:

if your network adapter requires firmware, ensure it is available. To test, unload & reload the adapter driver, then see dmesg | tail -50 or so: if there is an error message about missing firmware file among the network adapter start-up messages, make note of the filename. Then check your distribution's package database if the named file is available in some firmware package, and install that package if available. If the correct firmware file is not provided by your distribution (e.g. because you use a bleeding-edge custom kernel), look for it in linux-firmware git repository - when you find it, use the plain link at the right-most column to download it.
the cable is disconnected or broken - fix it.
the device at the other end of the cable is not powered on - fix it.
the switch port the cable is connected to has been disabled by the network administrator - ask the network administrator to enable it. (If disabled because the cable is plugged into a wrong port, then fix that too.)
the device at the one end of the cable supports Energy-Efficient Ethernet (EEE for short), and is switching speeds so fast the older device at the other end cannot keep up, causing a loss of link. In this case, ethtool --set-eee <NIC name> eee off might help if the computer is the newer device.
the switch port your cable is plugged into might be broken - try another port.
the network card might be damaged - test the cable+switch port with a different NIC/server if possible.
you may have found a rare NIC/switch incompatibility - test with another switch of a different model, if possible.


Ok, that explains why I have not found a lot of information on the property. Thanks!

@telcoM you said "The WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER reflects the state of the LINK light" do you have a source for that? I'd like to read more about the property, but I didn't find any info in the man page nor online yet.

@nullromo More properly, the state of Linux networking interface flag IFF_LOWER_UP, when available, is passed directly into NetworkManager attribute WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER. See function device_update_interface_flags() in src/core/devices/nm-device.c in NetworkManager source code. And the Linux kernel flag IFF_LOWER_UP indicates the operational state of the interface, or essentially, the link state.
